How to create a type with the optional keys from another type and make them required?
Lets say I have the following type:
type Props = {
    title: string
    color?: string
    timeout?: number | boolean
}

I want to create a type with only color and timeout but required i.e.:
type RProps = RequiredOptional<Props>

resulting in
type RProps = {
    color: string
    timeout: number | boolean
}

Is that possible and how?

I found answers (like this) on how to get optional keys from a type but not how to do what I want. The best I got is:
type OptionalKeys<T extends object> = keyof {
    [K in keyof T as T extends Record<K, T[K]> ? never : K]: K
}
type RProps = {
    [key in OptionalKeys<Props>]: NonNullable<Props[key]>
}

which has 2 problems:

Isn't generic
VSCode/NVim show it's keys as (property) timeout: NonNullable<number | boolean | undefined> instead of (property) timeout: number | boolean


You can create the mapped type like this:
type RequiredOptional<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T extends Record<K, T[K]> ? never : K]-?: T[K];
};

or alterntively:
type RequiredOptional<T> = Required<{
  [K in keyof T as T extends Record<K, T[K]> ? never : K]: T[K];
}>;

and to use it:
type RProps = RequiredOptional<Props>;

You were close to the solution, what you needed was:

To use the Required utility or to remove the optional nature of a key by using '-?'
Use the never key inline instead of first getting the optional keys and then mapping them


I would go with this... pick all optional props and make them required using -?

type Props = {
    title: string
    color?: string
    timeout?: number | boolean
}
type OptionalProps<T extends object> =  {
    [K in keyof T as T extends Record<K, T[K]> ? never : K]-?: T[K]
}


type RProps = OptionalProps<Props>

Playground
